# Semantic-UI Error Template

Tags: validation, error-handling, semantic-ui

The default error container for semantic ui forms is simply a red box listing the errors, on where you put the semantic ui code of:

```
<div class="ui error message"></div>
```

Like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/suJO8.png

But what I'd like to do is change it so I can customize it and add my own headers to it.

In the semantic ui site, it says:

> The template for error messages can be modified by adjusting
>   settings.template.error

Could someone please tell me how I can work with the error template?
I don't have a clue on how to work with settings.template.error.

**Update:**

In addition to Rob's answer, I figured out from semantic ui documentation you can also code it this way:

```
$.fn.form.settings.templates.error = 
function(errors) 
{
  var html = '<div class="ui header">Error Detected:</div>'
  html += '<ul class="list">';
  $.each(errors, function(index, value) {
    html += '<li>' + value + '</li>';
  });
  html += '</ul>';
  return $(html);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Looking at the source) the error template is a function that takes an error list and returns the displayed html (as jquery element). This is the default implementation:

```js
error: function(errors) {
  var
    html = '<ul class="list">'
  ;
  $.each(errors, function(index, value) {
    html += '<li>' + value + '</li>';
  });
  html += '</ul>';
  return $(html);
}
```

You should try sth like:

```js
$('.ui.form').form({ /*...*/ }, 
 {
    templates: {
       error: function(errors){
          //...
          return $('<div class="ui header">Error Header</div>...');
       }
    }
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

Update, actually is this template:

```
$.fn.form.settings.templates.prompt = function(errors) {
  return $('<div/>')
    .addClass('ui red prompt label')
    .html(errors[0])
  ;
}
```